# Numbers are constantly adding up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to print the total price below every time the select box changes, but there is a continuous collection process. I want the Selectbox to change in price every time it changes, but the number constantly add up instead. How can I solve this?

```js
$(function() {
  let toplam = 0.00;
  $('#video_tur').change(function() {
    if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
      toplam += parseInt($(this).val());
      document.getElementById('video_fiyat').textContent = '€' + parseInt($(this).val()).toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('toplam_fiyat').textContent = '€' + parseInt(toplam).toFixed(2);
    } else {
      document.getElementById('video_fiyat').textContent = "€0.00";
    }
  });


  $('#altyazi_dil').change(function() {
    if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
      document.getElementById('altyazi_fiyat').textContent = '€' + parseInt($(this).val()).toFixed(2);
    } else {
      document.getElementById('altyazi_fiyat').textContent = "€0.00";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="video_tur" id="video_tur">
  <option>Lütfen Seçim Yapın</option>
  <option value="20">2D</option>
  <option value="80">3D</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="altyazi_dili" id="altyazi_dil">
  <option>Lütfen Seçim Yapın</option>
  <option value="40">Türkçe</option>
  <option value="100">Almanca</option>
  <option value="100">İngilizce</option>
</select>



<div class="pt-4 pb-4 pl-5 pr-5 border-bottom">
  <div class="icence-content active text-center" id="regular">
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-14">Video Tur</span>
      <span class="font-size-20 font-weight-semibold" id="video_fiyat">€0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-14">Video Seçenek</span>
      <span class="font-size-20 font-weight-semibold" id="altyazi_fiyat">€0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-14">Video Seslendirme</span>
      <span class="font-size-20 font-weight-semibold">€0.00</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-17">Toplam</span>
      <span class="font-size-23 font-weight-semibold" id="toplam_fiyat">€0.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `constantly collects`?

Comment: Are you talking about how the total keeps increasing? You have `toplam += parseInt($(this).val());` which is going to keep incrementing the variable.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin Yes, it is constantly collecting.

Comment: Did you mean to do just `toplam = parseInt($(this).val())`?

Comment: @Jacob Actually what I want to do is take the value values and show the total number when both selectboxes change.

Comment: @AlanaStephenson  Constantly collecting what? Please edit your question to clarify what you mean so that we don't have to image the context in which this code is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is adding them all up because you define your `toplam` variable at the top and never reset it when you change the values. This causes the new values to be infinitely added to the total.

Add a `<form>` element around your `<select>` elements and listen for the `change` event on the form.

I'd suggest that you use [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to get all the values from the form and then loop over them with the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method of the values array. This allows you to count up each value of each select every time one of the values in the select elements changes.

```js
$(function() {

  const $form = $('#price-form');
  const $videoFiyat = $('#video_fiyat');
  const $altyaziFiyat = $('#altyazi_fiyat');
  const $toplamFiyat = $('#toplam_fiyat');
  
  // Names of select elements to use as a filter.
  const selectNames = ['video_tur', 'altyazi_dili']
  
  $form.on('change', function(event) {
  
    // Get all current values from the form.
    let values = $form.serializeArray();
    
    // Get only the values from the select elements.
    let selectValues = values.filter(({ name }) => selectNames.includes(name));
    
    // Add all values together and fix with 2 decimals.
    let total = selectValues.reduce((acc, { value }) => {
      if (!isNaN(value)) {
        acc += parseFloat(value);
      }
      return acc;
    }, 0).toFixed(2);
    
    // Show total in HTML.
    $toplamFiyat.text(`€${total}`);
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="price-form">
  <select class="form-control" name="video_tur" id="video_tur">
    <option value="0">Lütfen Seçim Yapın</option>
    <option value="20">2D</option>
    <option value="80">3D</option>
  </select>

  <select class="form-control" name="altyazi_dili" id="altyazi_dil">
    <option value="0">Lütfen Seçim Yapın</option>
    <option value="40">Türkçe</option>
    <option value="100">Almanca</option>
    <option value="100">İngilizce</option>
  </select>
  </form>


<div class="pt-4 pb-4 pl-5 pr-5 border-bottom">
  <div class="icence-content active text-center" id="regular">
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-14">Video Tur</span>
      <span class="font-size-20 font-weight-semibold" id="video_fiyat">€0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-14">Video Seçenek</span>
      <span class="font-size-20 font-weight-semibold" id="altyazi_fiyat">€0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-14">Video Seslendirme</span>
      <span class="font-size-20 font-weight-semibold">€0.00</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-17">Toplam</span>
      <span class="font-size-23 font-weight-semibold" id="toplam_fiyat">€0.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This way, it gives an error due to existing inputs. There are textarea and input in the form.

Comment: I've added a filter which will filter out only the values from the `video_tur` and `altyazi_dili` fields. It compares the `name` attribute value so make sure that they are the same if you'll edit your form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but you have not clearly explained what is behavior that you want.

```js
let toplam = 0.00;

function recalculate () {

    let video_tur = parseFloat( $('#video_tur').val() );
    if (Number.isNaN(video_tur)) {
      video_tur = 0;
    }

    let altyazi_dil = parseFloat( $('#altyazi_dil').val() );
    if (Number.isNaN(altyazi_dil)) {
      altyazi_dil = 0;
    }

    toplam += video_tur + altyazi_dil;

    var video_fiyat = document.getElementById('video_fiyat');
    var altyazi_fiyat = document.getElementById('altyazi_fiyat');
    var toplam_fiyat = document.getElementById('toplam_fiyat')

    video_fiyat.textContent  = '€'+ video_tur.toFixed(2);
    altyazi_fiyat.textContent  = '€'+ altyazi_dil.toFixed(2);
    toplam_fiyat.textContent = '€'+ toplam.toFixed(2);
} 


$(function() {
  $('#video_tur').change(recalculate);
  $('#altyazi_dil').change(recalculate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="video_tur" id="video_tur">
  <option>Lütfen Seçim Yapın</option>
  <option value="20">2D</option>
  <option value="80">3D</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="altyazi_dili" id="altyazi_dil">
  <option>Lütfen Seçim Yapın</option>
  <option value="40">Türkçe</option>
  <option value="100">Almanca</option>
  <option value="100">İngilizce</option>
</select>



<div class="pt-4 pb-4 pl-5 pr-5 border-bottom">
  <div class="icence-content active text-center" id="regular">
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-14">Video Tur</span>
      <span class="font-size-20 font-weight-semibold" id="video_fiyat">€0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-14">Video Seçenek</span>
      <span class="font-size-20 font-weight-semibold" id="altyazi_fiyat">€0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-14">Video Seslendirme</span>
      <span class="font-size-20 font-weight-semibold">€0.00</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="fiyatlandirma">
      <span class="font-size-17">Toplam</span>
      <span class="font-size-23 font-weight-semibold" id="toplam_fiyat">€0.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```